# Packaging python libraries with version-specific (2/3) code

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

I have a Python library written to work under both Python 2 and Python 3, with all the version-specific code localized in one module that exists in two variants, one source code file for Python 2 and one for Python 3. Each file contains code that raises a SyntaxError if imported into the wrong Python version.

When I package my library with distutils and install it, I always get a syntax error report for one or the other file. Is there a way to get rid of this? Ideally, I would like to tell distutils/setuptools to ignore the file that is not for the currently running Python version.

Comment: Why not merge the two files? It is perfectly feasible to write code that runs on either.

Comment: That's what I did for most of the modules, but when I need something in one version that's a syntax error in the other one, I need to keep the files apart. For example, I need to do a "del exec" in Python 3, which is a syntax error in Python 2 where exec is a keyword.

Comment: Why do you need to use `exec` *at all*?

Comment: I don't, otherwise I wouldn't want to del it. I am running code in a modified environment with limited __builtin__. Under Python 3, that includes disallowing exec.

Answer (score 0):

distutils imports all modules to byte-compile them (i.e. create the pyc and maybe pyo files) at build time and/or install time.  There is no option currently to have a module skipped.  You could write your setup script so that a different sdist is generated for Python 2 and Python 3 (so for example somemodule2.py would not be included in the Python 3 sdist), but not all tools work well with different sdists, including PyPI.

At the current time, I would try to make each module not raise a SyntaxError when imported by either Python 2 or 3.  Or I would follow Martijn’s advice and write just one module, possibly using the six modules, if the end result is not too messy (I’ve seen really horrible 2-and-3 code so I don’t like that solution, but a big part of the community has chosen it because it works).